# dropdown in bootstrap + instead of a list I want X columns of list from dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/vj35d1cu/1/).

Under `Dropdown1` is a list of actions, presented in 1 column.

I want to be able to present this list across more than 1 columns, lets say 5, or the page width.

I am hoping there is some `class` in bootstrap CSS that I can use to achieve this, but I may have to do some CSS.

How can I achieve this?

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

**EDIT1**

[this](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/vj35d1cu/4/) is what I am thinking using:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    height: 300%;
    width: 400%;
}
```

but his controls the dropdown area, I juest need to spread out the actions to fill this area.

**EDIT2**

[another](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/vj35d1cu/5/) possible way but this presents its own problems

```
ul .dropdown-menu li{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;//helps to determine number of columns, for instance 33.3% displays 3 columns
}
```

Comment: [slightly related](http://jsfiddle.net/A7MYE/4/)

Comment: tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/faxyz/4/) approach to control the size of the dropdown area but can get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You can use dropdowns within btn-gropus to do this.
See: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-nested

Note: You'll have to have 5 separate dropdowns using this method.

Comment: don't think that will work for what i want. I just want 1 dropdown, and then once clicked 5 columns,for example, would be displayed, as opposed to the current 1 column list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're ok with setting a width on the dropdown from your second example, try adding `display: inline-block` to the dropdown `li` elements.

```
.dropdown-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Here's your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vj35d1cu/6/) with that change. However that will affect your second dropdown so you may need to add a custom class to the first, if that's the only one you're wanting to apply these specific changes to.